# Use a form field as the entity key google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a form where a user logs in with a google account and then makes or updates their profile in google app engine.  I want to use the form field that contains their email address (which is automatically filled in with their user info from google) as the new entry's key.  This way I can easily update the entries since as long as they have the same email they will be the same entry.  Here is my form model and my page post and get methods, how can I modify them to set the key?

```
class Athlete(db.Model):                                         
    #fields to be added to the form
    norse_key = db.UserProperty()
    key_name = norse_key
    first_name = db.StringProperty()
    last_name = db.StringProperty()
    school_class = db.StringProperty()
    sex = db.StringProperty()
    home_address = db.StringProperty()
    city = db.StringProperty()
    state = db.StringProperty()
    zip = db.IntegerProperty()
    residence = db.StringProperty()
    SPO = db.IntegerProperty()
    cell = db.IntegerProperty
    sport_1 = db.StringProperty()
    sport_2 = db.StringProperty()
    sport_3 = db.StringProperty()

class AthleteForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Athlete()
class AthleteFormPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        self.response.out.write((user))
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Athlete WHERE norse_key = :1", user)
        item = None
        for item in query:
            self.response.out.write("%s,%s<br>" % (item.norse_key,item.first_name))    
        self.response.out.write('<div style="float:right"><a href="%s">Log Out</a> </div >'% (users.create_logout_url("/")))

        self.response.out.write('<html> <body> <a href="/">Submit A Treatment Log</a>  <form method="POST" action="/athleteformpage.html"> <table>')
        if item != None:
            self.response.out.write(AthleteForm(initial={'norse_key':item.norse_key,'first_name':item.first_name}))
        else:
            self.response.out.write(AthleteForm(initial={'norse_key':user}))
        self.response.out.write('</table> <input type="submit"> </form> </body> </html>')


    def post(self):
        data = AthleteForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
            entity = data.save(commit=False)
            entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
            entity.put()
            self.redirect('/athletes.html')
        else:
            # Reprint the form
            self.response.out.write('<html><body> <form method="POST" action="/athleteformpage.html"> <table>')
            self.response.out.write(data)
            self.response.out.write('</table> <input type="submit"> </form></body></html>')
```

Comment: unless the sex field can have values like "yes please" or "three time a week" it should be a BooleanProperty and not a StringProperty

Comment: The question is not clear... aren't you already doing this with `db.UserProperty()`? Would it work as you intend with `db.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)`? Or `user = users.get_current_user(); user_email = user.email()`?  It's difficult to answer a question that doesn't make sense.  Beyond that, [a user can change the email address for a Google account](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#Introduction), so it's a flawed premise.

Comment: Good call on the field, I'll make it a drop down menu, this project is still early in developnment.  And this app is going to be for a college that uses google domains, and you are not allow to change your college google email so that issue will not applied, but thanks for pointing it out for future reference.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen There are a lot of people who would prefer options other than "Male" or "Female". Gender is not a binary choice.

Comment: @marblecatdog The user's email address isn't a form field - it's a completely separate API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every entity in GAE datastore has a key, the key can be an id or string.
When creating an entity you can specify which value the key will have using the key_name atribute. for example:

```
Athlete.get_or_insert(key_name=name, ....)
```

You can remove the key_name that you put in your model and use the one that comes "out of the box"

to query for an entity using a key_name use `Athlete.get_by_key_name(name)`.
Due notice that key is case sensitive so you probbely need to make it canonical (by lower casing it and also probably url decoding it)

Comment: Not clear from this answer: The key name applies only to string values. Int values are IDs, and the two are mutually exclusive.